# Omnet++, How can I get list of all scheduled events of a module?

Tags: omnet++

I am scheduling list of events against a node in omnet++ using:

`scheduleAt(simTime().dbl() + slotTime, msg)`

and there could be multiple such schedule in future event list for a single module.

Now at a given time instant I want to cancel all future scheduled events of a node and that's why I need list of all future events.

To the best of my knowledge `cancelEvent(msg)` only cancel one event. How can I find the list and remove all events. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access a list of **all** future events one can use `getMessageQueue()`. And to remove only own events (i.e. selfmessages) every event in that list has to be checked using `isSelfMessage()`. The sample code, which removes all selfmessages from future event set:

```
cMessageHeap& heap = cSimulation::getActiveSimulation()->getMessageQueue();
cMessageHeap::Iterator it(heap);
do {
    cMessage * event = it();
    if (event && event->isSelfMessage()) {
        cancelAndDelete(event);
        it.init(heap);
    } else {
        it++;
    }

} while (!it.end());
```

Comment: Unfortunately this solution is not going to work with OMNeT++ Version 5.0 and above.
Changelog says: `cSimulation: removed msgQueue and getMessageQueue(); added getFES()
        as replacement (returns cFutureEventSet*)`