# How to cancel all events

Tags: omnet++

I want to cancel all my events; I have checked the following topic - 
 [Omnet++, How can I get list of all scheduled events of a module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35715383/omnet-how-can-i-get-list-of-all-scheduled-events-of-a-module?rq=1)

But in this link author explains how to do it in OMNeT++ for lower version.

I've also used `getFES()` instead of `getMessageQueue(), and`cFutureEventSet`instead of`cMessageHeap. But the problem is that the input value of the function `{cancelAndDelete(cMessage)}`and FES members are `cEvent`.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cause no one answer to my question I find out a way to solve my problem. I'll share it maybe it will be useful for some one else.

first point : we can't cancel events made by a module with another module;
second : it's more easier to handle our events and our schedule and CancelandDelete them whenever we want;